surface $X$ is a surface of revolution if and only if there is a line $L$ such that all planes through $L$ meet $X$ in geodesics.
I try to solve Exercise $122$ on page 40 of this pdf

Show that the surface $X$ is a surface of revolution if and only if there is a line $L$ such that all planes through $L$ meet $X$ in geodesics.

Let $L$ be z axis.
Then $x-ky=0$ is a plane through $L$.
Let the surface $X$ meet the plane $x-ky=0$ at the curve $\mathbf{r}(t)=(x(t),y(t),z(t))$.
Let the surface $X$ be given by the equation $f(x,y,z)=0$ for some function $f:\mathbf{R}^3\to\mathbf{R}$.
Since the normal to $X$ is $\nabla f$,
By assumption, $\mathbf{r}(t)$ is a geodesic, then
$$x''(t)\Big/ \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=y''(t)\Big/ \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=z''(t)\Big/ \frac{\partial f}{\partial z}$$
Since $\mathbf{r}(t)$ lies on the plane, $x(t)=ky(t)$ for all $t$.
so $x''(t)=ky''(t)$ for all $t$. Eliminating $k$,
$$x\Big/ \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=y\Big/ \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$$
so
$$y\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}-x\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=0$$
Let $f(x,y,z)=g(r,\theta,z),x=r\cos\theta,y=r\sin\theta$,
then$$\frac{\partial g}{\partial\theta}=0$$
So
$$f(x, y,z)=h(r,z)$$
so $L$ is the axis of revolution.

Why not think more geometrically? A regular curve is a geodesic in a surface $S$ if and only if its principal normal is the surface normal.

This is Exercise 122 on p. 40 of your link!  I was thinking of the proof of $\implies$. For the interesting direction, I would start by asking if these planar geodesics must also be lines of curvature.

@TedShifrin Yes. Sorry my number was wrong. I will edit it.
